# Walking Git History

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I've recently taken an interest in analyzing commit history to find files with a lot of churn. The idea being that high churn files are likely targets for refactoring. Right now it's a simple console app that returns the number of times a given file was committed. (Renames are not currently followed. It's a known area for improvement.)

The basic design is to have a visitor walk the commit graph and raise events for a listener to gather information about them. Currently there is a single listener that diffs each commit with its parents and caches those diffs. This should be flexible enough to create another one that, say, collects committer stats though.

[GitNStats v1.0.1 is on Github](https://github.com/rubberduck203/GitNStats/tree/b7f3da1fec625ddf4b193fc8740dede18fc098dc) if you prefer to view it there.

#### Visitor.cs

```
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace GitNStats
{
    public abstract class Visitor
    {
        public delegate void VisitedHandler(CommitVisitor visitor, Commit commit);
        public event VisitedHandler Visited;

        public abstract void Walk(Commit commit);

        protected virtual void OnVisited(CommitVisitor visitor, Commit commit)
        {
            Visited?.Invoke(visitor, commit);
        }
    }
}
```

#### CommitVisitor.cs

Git's commit history isn't a tree, it's a graph and we don't want to visit any commit more than once, so this class needs to keep track of the commits it's already visited.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace GitNStats
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Walks the commit graph back to the beginning of time.
    /// Guaranteed to only visit a commit once.
    /// </summary>
    public class CommitVisitor : Visitor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Walk the graph from this commit back.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="commit">The commit to start at.</param>
        public override void Walk(Commit commit)
        {
            Walk(commit, new HashSet<string>());
        }

        private void Walk(Commit commit, ISet<string> visited)
        {
            if (visited.Contains(commit.Sha))
            {
                // Exit so we don't walk the same path multiple times.
                return;
            }

            visited.Add(commit.Sha);
            OnVisited(this, commit);

            foreach(var parent in commit.Parents)
            {
                Walk(parent, visited);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Listener.cs

```
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace GitNStats
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Listens for a <see cref="Visitor"/> to raise the <see cref="Visitor.Visited"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    public interface Listener
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// To be executed whenever a visitor vistis a commit.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="visitor">The <see cref="Visitor"/> that raised the <see cref="Visitor.Visited"/> event.</param>
        /// <param name="visited">The <see cref="Commit"/> currently being visited.</param>
        void OnCommitVisited(Visitor visitor, Commit visited);
    }
}
```

#### DiffListener.cs

This is the class performs a diff that is roughly equivalent to a `git log --stat` and caches them for later use.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace GitNStats
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When a Commit is visited, compares that commit to it's parents 
    /// and stores the resulting TreeEntryChanges in the <see cref="Diffs"/> property.
    /// </summary>
    public class DiffListener : Listener
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;
        private readonly ConcurrentBag<TreeEntryChanges> _diffs = new ConcurrentBag<TreeEntryChanges>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The diff cache. 
        /// Clients should wait until the <see cref="Visitor"/> is done walking the graph before accessing.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<TreeEntryChanges> Diffs => _diffs;

        public DiffListener(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares the <paramref name="visited"/> commit to it's parents and caches the diffs in <see cref="Diffs"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="visitor">The <see cref="Visitor"/> that raised the <see cref="Visitor.Visited"/> event.</param>
        /// <param name="visited">The <see cref="Commit"/> currently being visited.</param>
        public void OnCommitVisited(Visitor visitor, Commit visited)
        {
            foreach (var parent in visited.Parents)
            {
                var diff = _repository.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree, visited.Tree);

                foreach (var changed in diff)
                {
                    _diffs.Add(changed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Program.cs

Last, but not least, the main program. 
(And easily the code most in need of some love.)

```
using System;
using LibGit2Sharp;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using CommandLine;

namespace GitNStats
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            return Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
                .MapResult(options =>
                {
                    var repoPath = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.RepositoryPath)
                        ? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                        : options.RepositoryPath;

                    return RunAnalysis(repoPath, options.BranchName);
                }, _ => 1);
        }

        private static int RunAnalysis(string repositoryPath, string branchName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var repo = new Repository(repositoryPath))
                {
                    var branch = (branchName == null) ? repo.Head : repo.Branches[branchName];
                    if (branch == null)
                    {
                        WriteError($"Invalid branch: {branchName}");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"Repository: {repositoryPath}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Branch: {branch.FriendlyName}");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    var listener = new DiffListener(repo);
                    var visitor = new CommitVisitor();
                    visitor.Visited += listener.OnCommitVisited;

                    visitor.Walk(branch.Tip);

                    var changeCounts = listener.Diffs
                        .GroupBy(c => c.Path)
                        .Select(x => new {Path = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
                        .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count);

                    Console.WriteLine("Commits\tPath");
                    foreach (var summary in changeCounts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{summary.Count}\t{summary.Path}");
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            catch (RepositoryNotFoundException)
            {
                WriteError($"{repositoryPath} is not a git repository.");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        private static void WriteError(string message)
        {
            var currentColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            try
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = currentColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### CommitVisitor

Using `Set<T>.Contains()` and returning if it evaluates to `true`makes the intent of the code more clear but internally if the element isn't in the `Set<T>` a second check is performed by calling `Add()`. So if speed should be an issue you should consider to check

```
if (!visited.Add(commit.Sha)) { return; }
```

---

#### Listener

I don't quite get it. In the XML doc of the interface it states

> Listens for a `<see cref="Visitor"/>` to raise the `<see
>   cref="Visitor.Visited"/>` event.

which would maybe make sense if we look at the name of the only method which needs to be implemented but usually I wouldn't expect an `OnXXX` method to be part of an interface but be a `protected` or even `private` method of a class which purpose is to just raise the event.

---

Comment: It's YAGNI. I was thinking I might want to use reflection to load listeners later. Truth be told, I don't even need that interface. Thanks for the review Heslacher.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public abstract class Visitor
> {
>     public delegate void VisitedHandler(CommitVisitor visitor, Commit commit);
> ```

Well, having your abstract class rely on its inheritors like that makes it pretty much useless. This should be declared like this.

```
public abstract class Visitor
{
    public delegate void VisitedHandler(Visitor visitor, Commit commit);
```